# (C++) Parse tree for evaluating simple arithmetic expressions returning incorrect value

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, arithmetic-expressions, parse-tree

I attempted to write a function that takes a simple arithmetic equation, converts it into a parse tree, and returns the evaluated value. For some reason, the value being returned is not correct at all. (Not that it helps, but the same function coded in Python works correctly). I've rechecked multiple times but I'm not able to locate the problem. I've tested the `BinaryTree` class and the `build_parse_tree()` function and they seem to work as intended. I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the `eval_parse_tree()` function. Please let me know what the issue is with this implementation.

And yes, I know that this implementation only works for single-digit numbers, but that shouldn't be a problem here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class BinaryTree{
private:
    char root;
    BinaryTree * left = NULL;
    BinaryTree * right = NULL;
public:
    BinaryTree(char root_val){
        // constructor
        root = root_val;
    }
    void insert_right(char value){
        BinaryTree * new_node = new BinaryTree(value);
        if(right == NULL)
            right = new_node;
        else{
            new_node -> right = right;
            right = new_node;
        }
    }
    void insert_left(char value){
        BinaryTree * new_node = new BinaryTree(value);
        if(left == NULL)
            left = new_node;
        else{
            new_node -> left = left;
            left = new_node;
        }
    }
    BinaryTree * get_right(){
        return right;
    }
    BinaryTree * get_left(){
        return left;
    }
    char get_root(){
        return root;
    }
    void set_root(char value){
        root = value;
    }
};

bool is_operator(char token){
    string ops = "+-/*";
    for(unsigned long long int i = 0; i < ops.length(); i++)
        if(ops[i] == token)
            return true;
    return false;
}

BinaryTree * build_parse_tree(string expr){
    vector <BinaryTree *> stack;
    BinaryTree * tree = new BinaryTree(' ');
    stack.push_back(tree);
    for(long long unsigned int i = 0; i < expr.length(); i++){
        if(expr[i] == '('){
            tree -> insert_left(' ');
            stack.push_back(tree);
            tree = tree -> get_left();
        }
        else if(isdigit(expr[i])){
            tree -> set_root(expr[i]);
            tree = stack.back();
            stack.pop_back();
        }
        else if(is_operator(expr[i])){
            tree -> set_root(expr[i]);
            tree -> insert_right(' ');
            stack.push_back(tree);
            tree = tree -> get_right();
        }
        else{
            tree = stack.back();
            stack.pop_back();
        }
    }
    return tree;
}

int eval_parse_tree(BinaryTree * tree){
    //cout << "Root: " << tree -> get_root() << endl;
    char op;
    int left, right;
    BinaryTree * left_child = tree -> get_left();
    BinaryTree * right_child = tree -> get_right();
    if(left_child && right_child){
        op = tree -> get_root();
        left = eval_parse_tree(left_child);
        right = eval_parse_tree(right_child);
        switch(op){
            case '+': return (int)left + (int)right;
            case '-': return (int)left - (int)right;
            case '*': return (int)left * (int)right;
            case '/': return (int)left / (int)right;
        }
    }
    else
        return tree -> get_root();
}

int main(void){
    cout << eval_parse_tree(build_parse_tree("(5+(2*7))")) << endl; //returns 2803, instead of 19
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: I guess your expectation is wrong. `'5' + '2' * '7'` is exactly `2803`. On the other hand `5 + 2 * 7` is `19`, but that's not what you were calculating ;)

Comment: Why are you adding space characters to the tree?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I guess since I never followed a structured study program, the use of a debugger was something I thought I never needed. Guess it's time now. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @churill I actually did typecast the char to an int inside the switch case statements, which should've worked. Do you have any idea why they didn't?

Comment: @molbdnilo I did it to represent an empty node. In hindsight, it's useless and I should probably remove the constructor as well.

Comment: @Blazy In the code you posted, the only things you're casting are `left` and `right`, which are already of type `int`, so those casts are complete no-ops. But even if you did cast the result of `tree -> get_root()`, that wouldn't change anything. It's already implicitly converted to `int` when you return it from an `int` function and making that conversion explicit won't affect the result. Note that casting an `int` to `char` only affects the type of the result, not the value.

Comment: @sepp2k I see. I guess I have a lot more learning to do! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing calculations with characters and not with integers. As you might know each character has a Ascii-code, a numerical representation of this character, which is used for calculations. Ascii codes for `'5'`, `'2'` and `'7'` are 53, 50 and 55.

Thus `'5' + '2' * '7'` is indeed 2083, because it's actually `53 + 50 * 55`.

A simple fix would be to replace

```
return tree -> get_root();
```

in `eval_parse_tree` with

```
return tree -> get_root() - '0';
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Although, I might want to change my code to avoid using this.